# Functional programming: pair items in list

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I have an array that I would like to re-order by grouping items together. e.g:

`[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0] => [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]`

OR

`[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0] => [[1, 1], [0], [1, 1], [0, 0]]`

In this example, 1s have been grouped together with a *maximum group size of 2 items*. I do not want to group all items together – I only want to pair values.

What's the best way to write my function? Reduce? Sort? I'm looking for a clean solution using functional programming techniques, preferably in multiple steps if this allows for better abstractions. I'm using JavaScript but I'll accept any language as an answer, if the logic is clear.

Some background: I have a list of photos and I want to re-order the list so that *square photos* (aka `1` in my example) appear side-by-side in the list.

Comment: So every "non-1" items should be left alone, and every 2 "1" items should be drawn together to the position of the first one?

Comment: Exactly that! @Bergi

Comment: Actually, `[[1, 1], 0, [1, 1], 0, 0]` would make more sense to me. Does your second format require exactly one array of "non-1"s between each pair?

Comment: What should happen if there is an odd number of 1s?

Comment: @Bergi The format you describe works too. Whatever makes most sense – some times it doesn't make sense to mix value types in an array, that's all.

Comment: @Bergi The maximum group size is 2 items, so for an odd number of 1s: [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0] => [[1, 1], [1], [0], [1, 1], [0, 0]]

Comment: Couldn't that last one also be `[[1,1],[0],[1,1],[0,0],[1]]`? How do you decide which way to group?

Comment: @elclanrs It could be, although only `1` values can have their position changed in order to be grouped.

Comment: @elclanrs Good point. I would prefer the left value to stay in its current position, but I would be interested to see both approaches.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the best way to write my function?

Probably in an imperative, yet pure way - we are looking for an `O(n)` solution.

> Reduce?

Well, basically every array traversal is a `reduce` of some sort. So we can definitely use it, but it doesn't necessarily make the code more readable in JavaScript.

> Sort?

No. We're not sorting your list.

> I'm looking for a clean solution using functional programming techniques, preferably in multiple steps if this allows for better abstractions. I'm using JavaScript but I'll accept any language as an answer, if the logic is clear.

Well, in Haskell it would probably look like

```hs
import Control.Arrow
import Data.Either

groupRightPairs = groupNRights 2

groupNRights :: Int -> [Either a b] -> [Either a [b]]
groupNRights 0 xs          = undefined
groupNRights n []          = []
groupNRights n (Left x:xs) = Left x : groupNRights n xs
groupNRights n xs          = uncurry (:) $ first Right $ second (groupNRights n) $ spanNRights n xs
                          {- let (rs, rest) = spanNRights n xs
                             in (Right rs) : (groupNRights n rest) -}
  where
    spanNRights :: Int -> [Either a b] -> ([b], [Either a b])
    spanNRights 0 xs = ([], xs)
    spanNRights n [] = ([], [])
    spanNRights n (Left x:xs) = second ((Left x):) (spanNRights n xs)
    spanNRights n (Right x:xs) = first (x:) (spanNRights (n-1) xs)
```

However, JavaScript does not have cons-lists, so while you *could* translate this into JS it does not look as good any more (though without the type restrictions it gets a bit simpler). Instead, you'll rather do this:

```
function getOnePairs(arr) {
    return getOneGroups(arr, n);
}
function getOneGroups(arr, n) {
    var result = [],
        group = [];
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != 1) {
            result.push(arr[i]);
        } else {
            if (group.length >= n)
                result.push(group = []);
            group.push(arr[i]); // this mutation is not very functional
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```